# Google Cloud Messaging: Lifetime of a Message

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

does anyone knows how long Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) keeps messages in queue and try resending them if the device is not reachable for any reason?

Can you please provide some links with the information about that?

Comment: Where have you searched for this information yet?

Comment: I did search on google but couldn't find exact number of days that GCM keeps queue alive. Maybe my keywords were not correct. Do you know where can I find it?

Comment: @NarendraOjha you can see `time_to_live` field in this documentation. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json

Comment: @rusted brain, Thanks for sharing that link.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution :) As they said "The default timeout is 4 weeks, unless the time_to_live flag is set.".

More information about lifetime of a message can be found at http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/project/android/docs/google/gcm/adv.html

Hope it will save your time :)